# Domain on fields.reference

Tags: odoo

I would like to modify the document selection field in OpenERP subscription.

```
'doc_source': fields.reference('Source Document', required=True,
selection=_get_document_types, size=128, 
help="User can choose the source document on which he wants to create documents"),
```

It allow you first to select the model, then in a second field to select the document. What I would like is to filter the document to only draft document (for instance invoice). Is it possible to setup a domain on this second field ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to do it but you need to do it manually. You need to override name_search / search method of the model , that you are selecting from the reference field, by adding your condition like ('state','=','draft') and it will work for you.

Comment: Does this mean it will affect all fields.reference (not only for subscription) pointing on the same kind of documents (in this case invoices). Is there no way to have the same effect but limited to subscriptions ?